# How to create bezeir curve bottom navigation bar in android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I want my bottom navigation view to be slightly curved from the center. To do this
currently, I am using the below code which is working fine but it curves from inside instead of from the top.

```
public class CustomBottomNavigationView1 extends BottomNavigationView {

    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private static final String TAG = "CustomView";

    /**
     * the CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS represent the radius of the fab button
     */
    private final int CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS = 128 / 2;
    // the coordinates of the first curve
    private Point mFirstCurveStartPoint = new Point();
    private Point mFirstCurveEndPoint = new Point();
    private Point mFirstCurveControlPoint1 = new Point();
    private Point mFirstCurveControlPoint2 = new Point();

    //the coordinates of the second curve
    private Point mSecondCurveStartPoint = new Point();
    private Point mSecondCurveEndPoint = new Point();
    private Point mSecondCurveControlPoint1 = new Point();
    private Point mSecondCurveControlPoint2 = new Point();
    private int mNavigationBarWidth;
    private int mNavigationBarHeight;


    public CustomBottomNavigationView1(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public CustomBottomNavigationView1(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public CustomBottomNavigationView1(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mPath = new Path();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.copper));
        setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        // get width and height of navigation bar
        // Navigation bar bounds (width & height)
        mNavigationBarWidth = getWidth();
        mNavigationBarHeight = getHeight();
        // the coordinates (x,y) of the start point before curve
        mFirstCurveStartPoint.set((mNavigationBarWidth / 2) - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 3) - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 3), 0);
        // the coordinates (x,y) of the end point after curve
        mFirstCurveEndPoint.set(mNavigationBarWidth / 2, CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4));
        // same thing for the second curve
        mSecondCurveStartPoint = mFirstCurveEndPoint;
        mSecondCurveEndPoint.set((mNavigationBarWidth / 2) + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 3) + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 3), 0);

        // the coordinates (x,y)  of the 1st control point on a cubic curve
        mFirstCurveControlPoint1.set(mFirstCurveStartPoint.x + CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4), mFirstCurveStartPoint.y);
        // the coordinates (x,y)  of the 2nd control point on a cubic curve
        mFirstCurveControlPoint2.set(mFirstCurveEndPoint.x - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) + CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS, mFirstCurveEndPoint.y);

        mSecondCurveControlPoint1.set(mSecondCurveStartPoint.x + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) - CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS, mSecondCurveStartPoint.y);
        mSecondCurveControlPoint2.set(mSecondCurveEndPoint.x - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4)), mSecondCurveEndPoint.y);

        // get width and height of navigation bar
        // Navigation bar bounds (width & height)
        mNavigationBarWidth = getWidth();
        mNavigationBarHeight = getHeight();
        // the coordinates (x,y) of the start point before curve
        mFirstCurveStartPoint.set((mNavigationBarWidth / 2) - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 3), 0);
        // the coordinates (x,y) of the end point after curve
        mFirstCurveEndPoint.set(mNavigationBarWidth / 2, CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4));
        // same thing for the second curve
        mSecondCurveStartPoint = mFirstCurveEndPoint;
        mSecondCurveEndPoint.set((mNavigationBarWidth / 2) + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 3), 0);

        // the coordinates (x,y)  of the 1st control point on a cubic curve
        mFirstCurveControlPoint1.set(mFirstCurveStartPoint.x + CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4), mFirstCurveStartPoint.y);
        // the coordinates (x,y)  of the 2nd control point on a cubic curve
        mFirstCurveControlPoint2.set(mFirstCurveEndPoint.x - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) + CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS, mFirstCurveEndPoint.y);

        mSecondCurveControlPoint1.set(mSecondCurveStartPoint.x + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2) - CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS, mSecondCurveStartPoint.y);
        mSecondCurveControlPoint2.set(mSecondCurveEndPoint.x - (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS + (CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS / 4)), mSecondCurveEndPoint.y);

        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(0, 0);
        mPath.lineTo(mFirstCurveStartPoint.x, mFirstCurveStartPoint.y);

        mPath.cubicTo(mFirstCurveControlPoint1.x, mFirstCurveControlPoint1.y,
                mFirstCurveControlPoint2.x, mFirstCurveControlPoint2.y,
                mFirstCurveEndPoint.x, mFirstCurveEndPoint.y);

        mPath.cubicTo(mSecondCurveControlPoint1.x, mSecondCurveControlPoint1.y,
                mSecondCurveControlPoint2.x, mSecondCurveControlPoint2.y,
                mSecondCurveEndPoint.x, mSecondCurveEndPoint.y);

        mPath.lineTo(mNavigationBarWidth, 0);
        mPath.lineTo(mNavigationBarWidth, mNavigationBarHeight);
        mPath.lineTo(0, mNavigationBarHeight);
        mPath.close();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }
}
```

Output from the above code:
[image: Bottom Curve image]

But I wanted the curve to go above the bottom navigation view not inside it.
Below is the result that I want:
[image: Top Curve Image]

Comment: [0,0] is the top-left corner. So since you're adding the CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS everywhere, it's going to go downwards.  What happens if you reverse your logic - deducting the radius instead?

Comment: The curve becomes straight when I decrease the CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS to around 40 - 0. And same with the negative value also.

Comment: It's probably not becoming straight, but falling out of view's draw bounds (drawing rectangle)

Comment: So what should i do next?

Comment: try a proof of concept, set the view's height to 400, change it's `onDraw` to draw it as 300 with your besier curve going upward instead of downward. if that seems to be going in the right direction (the curve "pops up") you'll want to make a view attribute to toggle the bar height and the curve height, and have the view's height be the sum of those two. you'll want to change the `onMeasure()` as well.

Comment: Can you share some code example?

Comment: have you found any solution ? @ps_who

Comment: @AshwinNirmale Not really. But you can try keeping the height of the parent layout greater than the CustomBottomNavigationView1 layout and give CURVE_CIRCLE_RADIUS any value less the 0 to make it curve from the top. And also if you manage to do it then please let me know as well.

Comment: @ps_who : check this. it might be solve you issue 
https://github.com/SimformSolutionsPvtLtd/SSCustomBottomNavigation